# dotMemory Unit Standalone launcher with XUnit hang at the end of the test

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab, xunit, dotmemory

I am using dotMemory Unit Standalone launcher on a gitlab CI server to lauch XUnit unit test.

The test succeed but the process hang at the end then the test is considered failed because it hit the timeout.
The test output the result before getting stuck

```
testing Test.Memory...
$ output\memorytools\dotMemoryUnit output\xunit.console.exe --work-dir=output --propagate-exit-code  --no-instrumentation --no-auto-cleanup --no-updates --log-level=VERBOSE -- UbikeyOfficeVerticalUiTest.dll -namespace %TestNamespace% -html test_results.html -verbose -stoponfail
dotMemory Unit 3.0 part of 2017.3  build 111.0.20171219.95427. Copyright (C) 2015-2017 JetBrains s.r.o.
xUnit.net Console Runner (64-bit Desktop .NET 4.0.30319.42000)
  Discovering: Test
  Discovered:  Test
  Starting:    Test
...
(test log)
...
      Finished:    Test
    === TEST EXECUTION SUMMARY ===
       Test  Total: 1, Errors: 0, Failed: 0, Skipped: 0, Time: 7.243s
```

I use the folowing command in the `gitlab-ci.yml` to lauch the test

```
'output\memorytools\dotMemoryUnit output\xunit.console.exe --work-dir=output --propagate-exit-code  --no-instrumentation --no-auto-cleanup --no-updates --log-level=VERBOSE -- Test.dll -namespace %TestNamespace% -html test_results.html -verbose -stoponfail'
```

The output folder contains the xunit.console executable and the test dll and it's dependencies. the memorytools folder containt everything from the tool folder of the JetBrains.dotMemoryUnit nuget package

The test is just:

```
[Retry]
        public void TestImageMemoryLeak()
        {         
            true.ShouldBeTrue();
        }
```

There is no problem when lauching test with Xunit without dotMemory.
Also the test do not hang when I lauch it with dotmemory localy on my computer.

Version used:

- JetBrains.dotMemoryUnit 3.0.20171
- xunit.runner.console 2.4.1
- GitLab Community Edition 11.4.5

Comment: What does [Retry] attribute mean? Is it a custom test attribute? Could you please provide its implementation?

Comment: It extend the Fact attribute.
(https://github.com/giggio/xunit-retry)

Comment: We can check whether there are any issues in dotMemory Unit logs.
Could you please add the next parameter after --log-level=VERBOSE:

--core-log-mask=MemoryDumpGt,GcCb,MetaDataGt,Snapshot,Api,Bridge,FieldResolverGt,ClassRecoveryGt,AppDomainRecoveryGt

The logs will be saved in %temp%\JetLogs folder.
Please zip all log files and send it to us. You can create support ticket and attach logs here: https://dotnettools-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/requests/new